# CSV file to a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file (named "test.csv") containing this list with tuples:

```
[('calculation', 1468171987.4406562, None), ('calculation', 1468171988.5840397, None), ('calculation', 1468171989.8159678, 1.9041595458984375)]5)]
```

How can I import this csv file and save its contents to a list like this:

```
record = []
```

after the import

```
record = [('calculation', 1468171987.4406562, None), ('calculation', 1468171988.5840397, None), ('calculation', 1468171989.8159678, 1.9041595458984375)]
```

This is what I tried:

```
import csv
    with open ("test.csv", 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        record = reader
```

Attempt 2:

```
import csv

with open ("test.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    record = list(reader)
```

Then I get this error:

```
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

Comment: You need to read lines with the reader. Simplest way: `record = list(reader)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
import ast
with open ("test.csv", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        list = ast.literal_eval(line)
        print list
```

Comment: That gives me this error:    ValueError: malformed node or string: b"    [('calculation', 1468177461.191623, 2.616061210632324), ('calculation',     1468177463.8076842, None), ('calculation', 1468177466.2713623,     None)]"      Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: Which python version are you using? with 2.7.6, I am not noticing any such error. I edited the code with minor modification. Please check new code once.

Comment: My mistake.  It was down to a syntax error on my part.  Your method works perfectly. Thank you so much, I've been trying to work this out for hours!

Comment: Quick question, how can I run this within a function?

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have a CSV reader (I assume your real code is indented correctly and runs without syntax error), you need to use it to input the lines from the file. The simplest way is like this:

```
record = list(reader)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm still trying to get down file i/o.  I'll post how I tried to do it with your method.  Thank you by the way.